# Ruby Logic comparisons with Nil

Tags: ruby, logic

I am having trouble understanding the following code:

```
vowels_arr = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
(0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? {|i| vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]}
```

When I try to run it WITHOUT the - 1, I get an error saying that I can't compare a string to nil. But what I dont understand is that why do we even need the -1?? The "..." ranger makes it so we are only evaluating "a","e","i","o" (4 out of the 5). Since the total length is 5 and we are already at 4 things to compare, my belief is that the comparison (vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr [i+1]) should work without the -1.

Can someone please explain to me why we need the -1 after array length?

Also are there other ways in ruby to get past this comparing to nil error?

Comment: What is `vowels_arr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
vowels_arr[i + 1]
```

`(0...(vowels_arr.length))` will return all indexes for the array.

```
(0...(vowels_arr.length)).to_a # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But then you're trying to get **next** index from current. If current index is last index (4), this results in an error, because you get `nil` where you expect a string (because element doesn't exist at non-existent index). That's why you need `length - 1`, to allow your logic not to go out of array's bounds.

By the way, if you're trying to check if the array is sorted, why not do it more directly?

```
vowels_arr = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
puts vowels_arr.sort == vowels_arr 
# >> true
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sergio answers, the problem is with `vowels_arr[i + 1]`. The variable `i` ranges over the indices of `vowels_arr`, and hence `i + 1` will not necessarily point to an existing index of `vowels_arr`. Particularly, when `i` reaches the last index, `i + 1` will be greater than the existing indices, and `vowels_arr[i + 1]` will be `nil`.

Also as Sergio answers, if your purpose is to see if it is sorted, then doing as Sergio's answer is straightforward, but in general cases, you can do it like this:

```
vowels_arr.each_cons(2).all?{|e1, e2| e1 <= e2}
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you. I think it is probably by the same person who did your downvote for probably the same reason.

Answer (score -1):

```
vowels_arr = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
p vowels_arr[vowels_arr.length] #=> nil
(0..(vowels_arr.length)).all? {|i| vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]}
#=> `<=': comparison of String with nil failed (ArgumentError)
```

As you are passing the `vowels_arr[vowels_arr.length]` element to the block,which is `nil`. In `Ruby` array's are `0(zero)` based. Thus `vowels_arr.length` gives `5` means elements are in the range of `(0..4)`. see below:

```
vowels_arr = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
p vowels_arr[0] #=> "a"
p vowels_arr[1] #=> "e"
p vowels_arr[2] #=> "i"
p vowels_arr[3] #=> "o"
p vowels_arr[4] #=> "u"
p vowels_arr[5] #=> nil
p vowels_arr[6] #=> nil
```

`(0..(vowels_arr.length))` means you are passing to the block `0,1,2,3,4,5`, and an attempt to access `5` gives `nil`, as in your array in `5th` index is `nil`. See why the code `(0...(vowels_arr.length)).all? {|i| vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]}` failed by the below debugging with `each` to see what has been passed to the block:

```
vowels_arr = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
(0...(vowels_arr.length)).each {|i| p vowels_arr[i],"--",vowels_arr[i+1]}
p (1...3).to_a
```

*Output:*

```
"a"
"--"
"e"
"e"
"--"
"i"
"i"
"--"
"o"
"o"
"--"
"u"
"u"
"--"
nil
```

Comment: sorry i am still having trouble understanding.  vowels_arr.length = 5 and the 0...5 should equal 4. What am I misunderstanding here? thanks

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. there's difference between `(a..b)` and `(a...b)`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev OP got the point, that's all. I used it intentionally to show him, how to use it.

Comment: @Priti: BTW, use backticks only for code. Don't put non-code in them. Like `OP` or `GOOGLE`.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem with OP's code. And therefore you're answering something else, not the actual question. Hence the downvote.